# Not getting sum of addition in Third textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add the sum of two numbers entered in two seprate textbox id is(`PaperHeight & MountHEight`) and then get the sum in third textbox id is (`FrameHeight`)

I want to get the output when the submit button is clicked

following is my code

```js
var PaperHeight = document.getElementById('PaperHeight').value; 
var PaperWeight = document.getElementById('PaperWeight').value;

var MountHeight = document.getElementById('MountHeight').value;
var MountWeight = document.getElementById('MountWeight').value;

var FrameHeight = document.getElementById('FrameHeight').value;
var FrameWeight = document.getElementById('FrameWeight').value;


var PrintingRate = document.getElementById('PrintingRate').value; 
var FrameRate = document.getElementById('FrameRate').value;


function btnclick(){
FrameHeight=PaperHeight+MountHeight;

}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Rate Calculator</h1>
        <br/>
       <form>
            
                             
           <br/>
           <div class="input-group">
            Paper:<span class="input-group-text">Height/Width</span>
            <input type="number"  class="form-control" id="PaperHeight">
            <input type="number"  class="form-control">
          </div>
          <br/>

          <div class="input-group">
            Mount:<span class="input-group-text">Height/Width</span>
            <input type="number" aria-label="First name" class="form-control" id="MountHeight">
            <input type="number" aria-label="Last name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <br/>

          <div class="input-group">
            Frame:<span class="input-group-text">Height/Weight</span>
            <input type="number" aria-label="First name" class="form-control" id="FrameHeight">
            <input type="number" aria-label="Last name" class="form-control">

          </div>
          <br/><br/>

          <div class="input-group">
            Printing Rate:<span class="input-group-text">Size</span>
            <input type="number" aria-label="First name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div class="input-group">
            Frame Rate:<span class="input-group-text">Size</span>
            <input type="number" aria-label="First name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div class="input-group">
            Mount Rate:<span class="input-group-text">Size</span>
            <input type="number" aria-label="First name" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <br/>
          <br/><br/>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="btnclick()">Submit</button>
           
       </form>





       <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

so please help me to get my output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move document.getElementById('PaperHeight').value code in side function.

```js
function btnclick() {
    var PaperHeight = document.getElementById('PaperHeight').value;
    var MountHeight = document.getElementById('MountHeight').value;
    var FrameHeight = document.getElementById('FrameHeight').value;
    document.getElementById('FrameHeight').value = parseInt(PaperHeight) + parseInt(MountHeight);
      }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Rate Calculator</h1>
        <br/>
       <form>
            
                             
           <br/>
           <div class="input-group">
            Paper:<span class="input-group-text">Height/Width</span>
            <input type="number"  class="form-control" id="PaperHeight">
            <input type="number"  class="form-control">
          </div>
          <br/>

          <div class="input-group">
            Mount:<span class="input-group-text">Height/Width</span>
            <input type="number" aria-label="First name" class="form-control" id="MountHeight">
            <input type="number" aria-label="Last name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <br/>

          <div class="input-group">
            Frame:<span class="input-group-text">Height/Weight</span>
            <input type="number" aria-label="First name" class="form-control" id="FrameHeight">
            <input type="number" aria-label="Last name" class="form-control">

          </div>
          <br/><br/>

          <div class="input-group">
            Printing Rate:<span class="input-group-text">Size</span>
            <input type="number" aria-label="First name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div class="input-group">
            Frame Rate:<span class="input-group-text">Size</span>
            <input type="number" aria-label="First name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div class="input-group">
            Mount Rate:<span class="input-group-text">Size</span>
            <input type="number" aria-label="First name" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <br/>
          <br/><br/>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="btnclick()">Submit</button>
           
       </form>
       <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why did you moved variables inside function and why did you add `parseInt` is it necessary to add `parseInt`

Comment: When we enter a value in the text box it should be bind. Input's value is string by default. I have used parseInt to convert in integer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the OP (**O**riginal **P**ost) code is more or less complete, your specific problem is not that your'e not getting anything displayed -- it actually should work. Unfortunately you probably didn't notice that the entire form resets itself. The default behavior of a form triggered by a submit event is to gather all [form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Basic_native_form_controls) with `name` attributes, send their `.value`s to a server, and then reset itself. To prevent this default behavior add the following as the first line within the [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events):

> ```
> event.preventDefault();
> ```

BTW [inline event attribute handlers are garbage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these), instead use either on event property handlers:

> ```
>  document.forms[0].onsubmit = handleSubmit;
> ```

Or an event listener:

> ```
>   document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
> ```

In the OP, the HTML layout was haphazard. There were extra `<input>` with no `#id` and no explination why the HTML had 9 `<input>`s but only 3 mentioned. So by going by what makes more sense I changed the calculations:

> - 3 Groups - Paper, Mount, Frame
> - 2 Inputs per Group - Height and Width
> - 3 Outputs - 1 Rate for each Group
> - Rate = Height x Width

Referencing the form and inputs was done by [`.forms` and `.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) property and the event object:

> ```
>   // add #id, [name], bracket notation [0] 
>   document.forms.rateCalculator;
>   /*
>  .currentTarget points to form and .elements are all form
>   controls
>   */
>   event.currentTarget.elements;
> ```

***Details are commented in example below***

```js
// Pass the event oject
const calculateRate = event => {
  // Stops the form from sending data
  event.preventDefault();
  // All form controls
  const io = event.currentTarget.elements;
  /*
  All values of all form controls
  are strings so if you need to
  calculate any value you must 
  convert the values to numbers
  */
  let pH = parseFloat(io.pHeight.value);
  let mH = parseFloat(io.mHeight.value);
  let fH = parseFloat(io.fHeight.value);

  let pW = parseFloat(io.pWidth.value);
  let mW = parseFloat(io.mWidth.value);
  let fW = parseFloat(io.fWidth.value);

  /*
  The ternary expression will
  display 0 instead of NaN
  */
  io.pRate.value = isNaN(pH * pW) ? 0 : pH * pW;
  io.mRate.value = isNaN(mH * mW) ? 0 : mH * mW;
  io.fRate.value = isNaN(fH * fW) ? 0 : fH * fW;
}

// Reference the form
const form = document.forms.rateCalculator;

// form will listen for the submit event
form.addEventListener('submit', calculateRate);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Calculate Rates</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container">
    <form id='rateCalculator'>
      <fieldset class='row pb-2'>
        <legend>
          <h1>Rate Calculator</h1>
        </legend>
        <fieldset class="form-group col-4 mb-3">
          <legend>Paper</legend>
          <label for='pHeight' class='label-control'>Height  </label>
          <input id='pHeight' class="form-control" type="number" min='0' value='0'>
          <label for='pWidth' class='label-control'>Width  </label>
          <input id='pWidth' class="form-control" type="number" min='0' value='0'>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group col-4 mb-3">
          <legend>Mount</legend>
          <label for="mHeight" class='label-control'>Height </label>
          <input id="mHeight" class="form-control" type="number" min='0' value='0'>
          <label for='mWidth' class="label-control">Width </label>
          <input id='mWidth' class="form-control" type="number" min='0' value='0'>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group col-4 mb-3">
          <legend>Frame</legend>
          <label for="fHeight" class='label-control'>Height </label>
          <input id="fHeight" class="form-control" type="number" min='0' value='0'>
          <label for='fWidth' class="label-control">Width </label>
          <input id='fWidth' class="form-control" type="number" min='0' value='0'>
        </fieldset>
        <hr>
        <fieldset class="row mt-1 mb-3">
          <legend>Rates</legend>
          <label for='pRate' class="col-2 col-form-label">Print: </label>
          <div class='col'>
            <input id='pRate' class="form-control-plaintext" readonly>
          </div><br>
          <label for='mRate' class="col-2 col-form-label">Mount: </label>
          <div class='col'>
            <input id='mRate' class="form-control-plaintext" readonly>
          </div><br>
          <label for='fRate' class="col-2 col-form-label">Frame: </label>
          <div class='col'>
            <input id='fRate' class="form-control-plaintext" readonly>
          </div><br>
        </fieldset>
       <div class='btn-group'>
        <button class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
         <button class='btn btn-danger' type='reset'>Reset</button>
         </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </main>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```